# How to prevent fractions in polynomial quotients?

Tags: pattern-matching, polynomials

(This was a hard question to give a succinct title to, so feel free to edit it.)

When I divide polynomials, I would like Mathematica to NOT create negative powers of variables.  For example:

```
expr = c*(p^2) + p^4 + c^2 + 2*p + 3*c + 1;
PolynomialQuotientRemainder[expr, c*(p^2) + c, p]
PolynomialQuotientRemainder[expr, c*(p^2) + c, c]
```

Results:

$\left\{\frac{p^2}{c}-\frac{1}{c}+1,c^2+2 c+2 p+2\right\}$

$\left\{\frac{c}{p^2+1}+\frac{p^2}{p^2+1}+\frac{3}{p^2+1},p^4+2 p+1\right\}$

I don't want fractions with variables in the quotients.

Desired result:

$\left\{1,c^2+2 c+p^4+2 p+1\right\}$

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `In[387]:= PolynomialReduce[c*(p^2) + p^4 + c^2 + 2*p + 3*c + 1, 
 c*(p^2) + c, {c, p}]

Out[387]= {{1}, 1 + 2 c + c^2 + 2 p + p^4}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) has supplied the answer in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103926/how-to-prevent-fractions-in-polynomial-quotients#comment282143_103926): use `PolynomialReduce`, rather than `PolynomialQuotientRemainder`. As such:

```
PolynomialReduce[expr, c*(p^2) + c, {c, p}]
(* -> {{1}, 1 + 2 c + c^2 + 2 p + p^4} *)
```

which is the desired result.

Comment: Yeah, Daniel does that a lot.  I wish there was an option to "Accept this Comment as the Answer".

Comment: From what I can tell, Daniel is not big on one-liner answers (he talks to me at times, which really unnerves his spouse).

Comment: @Daniel lol ---